# Ethereum - Exporting Accounts/Balances from full node

Tags: go-ethereum, ether, airdrop

I have a Ethereum full node that I will be using to take a snapshot for an airdrop for a project I am working on. The node is running and syncing.

The issue currently is that there doesn't seem to be much out there to show how to export a list of accounts and their balances in a CSV I can use to then use for our airdrop.

I've tried using the web3 dumpBlock method, but it takes far too long. I did something similar for BTC and it took only a few minutes.

How can I can the 'worldstate' of the chain and output the accounts and balances into a CSV?

Any direction would be help! Thanks!